# R - Line chart showing many values at X axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I created a line chart in R as seen in the link and you will notice that many points are lying near the X axis. Just wondering why the line chart is not showing properly.

I tried removing NAs as well as Zeroes from the budget numbers (plotted on Y axis) but still the same issue.

I used the following to create the line chart.

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=title_year,y=budget)) + geom_line()
```

Please let me know what you think could be the issue.

[image]

Comment: check what your data type is using class(). It looks like your data may contain factors instead of numeric data. If so convert your data using as.numeric().

Comment: Can you share your dataset?  Please, do that via pasting in your question the output of `dput(df)`.

Comment: Are you sure you have all years in your column? Looks like something is missing. Please share example of data, your full code, and consider a reprex https://community.rstudio.com/t/faq-whats-a-reproducible-example-reprex-and-how-do-i-do-one/5219